# Is it safe to enable JavaScript in Android Web View?

Tags: android, security, android-webview, android-security

The majority of my app features are loading in web view. What are the possible security threats if I enable JavaScript, and what are the remedies for them?

My web view code and details are added below.

- Web view settings.

  ```
   this.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
   this.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
   this.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
   this.settings.useWideViewPort = true
   this.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
  ```
- No HTTP traffic allowed in web view (App running in API 21 and above)
- No multi window support enabled in web view settings.
- Not using JavaScript interface.
- No domain restrictions are added. User can navigate to websites that are not in our control. I know we have to restrict the user to web pages that are under our control as per security best practices. What are the potential threats if I didn't do it?